# Class Packing and Alignment

Tags: c++, pragma

What is the alignment for calling `#pragma pack()` with no argument in GCC compiler?

Also, I often see that when we use `placement new` in creating object, the `class` is often being packed. What is the reason for that? Is it necessary to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the first part, you could have recklessly used google: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html

secondly there may be times when you need to control the binary format of your class. you may need to manage the amount of memory and the real binary offsets of data structures:

```
struct
{
  char c;
  int i;
};
```

may use 8 bytes of memory or 5 bytes of memory, according to machine type and pragma pack used.

Comment: For the first part, does that mean that I could just take out the #pragma pack() from the code?

Comment: depends on the code. if no other pragma pack is in the code, yes

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let say I have multiple class declaration in a .h file, does that mean that if I set #pragma pack(1) before a particular class, all classes below the #pragma pack(1) would utilized it? So I need to set it back to #pragma pack()? How about classes declared in other .h files?

Comment: that is correct. pragma pack() takes effect once found by the compiler and remains active as long as the compile is running, so also for all #included files afterwards. so if you want only one class to be packed #pragma pack(1) before the class declaration and #pragma pack() afterwards. on a sidenote: use pragma pack only when really needed, since it will have effects on execution speed (ok, not dramatically)

Comment: also if you find the answer useful, consider accepting or upvoting the answer ;-)